PanacheEntity record update works only once
I am learning qurkus and I have a problem that I can't update a record in the db more than once.
I use merge() to update my records:
@WithTransaction
    public Uni<User> update(User user) {
        return findById(user.id)
                .chain(u -> User.getSession())
                .chain(s -> s.merge(user));
    }

The first time everything works fine, but if I try to update the record again, I run into the following problem:
"details": "Error id b98d37fe-4753-409d-b46a-efe32cb84419-1, org.hibernate.HibernateException: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect) : [com.example.Services.User.User#2]"


"stack": "org.hibernate.HibernateException: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect) : [com.example.Services.User.User#2]
    at org.hibernate.reactive.session.impl.ReactiveExceptionConverter.convert(ReactiveExceptionConverter.java:28)
    at org.hibernate.reactive.session.impl.ReactiveSessionImpl.lambda$fireMerge$21(ReactiveSessionImpl.java:900)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniHandle(CompletableFuture.java:934)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniHandleStage(CompletableFuture.java:950)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.handle(CompletableFuture.java:2340)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.handle(CompletableFuture.java:144)
    at org.hibernate.reactive.session.impl.ReactiveSessionImpl.fireMerge(ReactiveSessionImpl.java:889)
    at org.hibernate.reactive.session.impl.ReactiveSessionImpl.reactiveMerge(ReactiveSessionImpl.java:872)
    at org.hibernate.reactive.mutiny.impl.MutinySessionImpl.lambda$merge$13(MutinySessionImpl.java:256)
    at io.smallrye.context.impl.wrappers.SlowContextualSupplier.get(SlowContextualSupplier.java:21)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.builders.UniCreateFromCompletionStage.subscribe(UniCreateFromCompletionStage.java:24)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.AbstractUni.subscribe(AbstractUni.java:36)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniRunSubscribeOn.lambda$subscribe$0(UniRunSubscribeOn.java:27)
    at org.hibernate.reactive.context.impl.VertxContext.execute(VertxContext.java:91)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniRunSubscribeOn.subscribe(UniRunSubscribeOn.java:25)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.AbstractUni.subscribe(AbstractUni.java:36)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnItemTransformToUni$UniOnItemTransformToUniProcessor.performInnerSubscription(UniOnItemTransformToUni.java:81)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnItemTransformToUni$UniOnItemTransformToUniProcessor.onItem(UniOnItemTransformToUni.java:57)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnItemConsume$UniOnItemComsumeProcessor.onItem(UniOnItemConsume.java:43)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnItemTransformToUni$UniOnItemTransformToUniProcessor.onItem(UniOnItemTransformToUni.java:60)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.builders.UniCreateFromKnownItem$KnownItemSubscription.forward(UniCreateFromKnownItem.java:38)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.builders.UniCreateFromKnownItem.subscribe(UniCreateFromKnownItem.java:23)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.AbstractUni.subscribe(AbstractUni.java:36)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnItemTransformToUni$UniOnItemTransformToUniProcessor.performInnerSubscription(UniOnItemTransformToUni.java:81)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnItemTransformToUni$UniOnItemTransformToUniProcessor.onItem(UniOnItemTransformToUni.java:57)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnItemTransformToUni$UniOnItemTransformToUniProcessor.onItem(UniOnItemTransformToUni.java:60)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.builders.DefaultUniEmitter.complete(DefaultUniEmitter.java:37)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.groups.UniOnNull.lambda$failWith$1(UniOnNull.java:46)
    at io.smallrye.context.impl.wrappers.SlowContextualBiConsumer.accept(SlowContextualBiConsumer.java:21)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.groups.UniOnItem.lambda$transformToUni$4(UniOnItem.java:177)
    at io.smallrye.context.impl.wrappers.SlowContextualConsumer.accept(SlowContextualConsumer.java:21)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.builders.UniCreateWithEmitter.subscribe(UniCreateWithEmitter.java:22)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.AbstractUni.subscribe(AbstractUni.java:36)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnItemTransformToUni$UniOnItemTransformToUniProcessor.performInnerSubscription(UniOnItemTransformToUni.java:81)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnItemTransformToUni$UniOnItemTransformToUniProcessor.onItem(UniOnItemTransformToUni.java:57)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnItemTransformToUni$UniOnItemTransformToUniProcessor.onItem(UniOnItemTransformToUni.java:60)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOperatorProcessor.onItem(UniOperatorProcessor.java:47)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.builders.UniCreateFromCompletionStage$CompletionStageUniSubscription.forwardResult(UniCreateFromCompletionStage.java:63)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:863)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:841)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:510)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2147)
    at org.hibernate.reactive.util.async.impl.AsyncTrampoline$TrampolineInternal.unroll(AsyncTrampoline.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.reactive.util.async.impl.AsyncTrampoline$TrampolineInternal.lambda$unroll$0(AsyncTrampoline.java:126)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:863)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:841)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:510)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2147)
    at io.vertx.core.Future.lambda$toCompletionStage$3(Future.java:581)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.future.FutureImpl$4.onSuccess(FutureImpl.java:176)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.future.FutureBase.emitSuccess(FutureBase.java:66)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.future.FutureImpl.tryComplete(FutureImpl.java:259)
    at io.vertx.sqlclient.impl.QueryResultBuilder.tryComplete(QueryResultBuilder.java:88)
    at io.vertx.sqlclient.impl.QueryResultBuilder.tryComplete(QueryResultBuilder.java:32)
    at io.vertx.core.Promise.complete(Promise.java:66)
    at io.vertx.core.Promise.handle(Promise.java:51)
    at io.vertx.core.Promise.handle(Promise.java:29)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.future.FutureImpl$4.onSuccess(FutureImpl.java:176)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.future.FutureBase.emitSuccess(FutureBase.java:66)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.future.FutureImpl.tryComplete(FutureImpl.java:259)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.future.PromiseImpl.onSuccess(PromiseImpl.java:49)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.future.PromiseImpl.handle(PromiseImpl.java:41)
    at io.vertx.sqlclient.impl.TransactionImpl.lambda$wrap$0(TransactionImpl.java:72)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.future.FutureImpl$4.onSuccess(FutureImpl.java:176)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.future.FutureBase.lambda$emitSuccess$0(FutureBase.java:60)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.execute(ContextImpl.java:298)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.DuplicatedContext.execute(DuplicatedContext.java:171)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.future.FutureBase.emitSuccess(FutureBase.java:57)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.future.FutureImpl.tryComplete(FutureImpl.java:259)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.future.PromiseImpl.onSuccess(PromiseImpl.java:49)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.future.PromiseImpl.handle(PromiseImpl.java:41)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.future.PromiseImpl.handle(PromiseImpl.java:23)
    at io.vertx.sqlclient.impl.command.CommandResponse.fire(CommandResponse.java:46)
    at io.vertx.sqlclient.impl.SocketConnectionBase.handleMessage(SocketConnectionBase.java:324)
    at io.vertx.pgclient.impl.PgSocketConnection.handleMessage(PgSocketConnection.java:114)
    at io.vertx.sqlclient.impl.SocketConnectionBase.lambda$init$0(SocketConnectionBase.java:137)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.emit(ContextImpl.java:328)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.emit(ContextImpl.java:321)
    at io.vertx.core.net.impl.NetSocketImpl.handleMessage(NetSocketImpl.java:388)
    at io.vertx.core.net.impl.ConnectionBase.read(ConnectionBase.java:159)
    at io.vertx.core.net.impl.VertxHandler.channelRead(VertxHandler.java:153)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:442)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436)
    at io.vertx.pgclient.impl.codec.PgDecoder.fireCommandResponse(PgDecoder.java:52)
    at io.vertx.pgclient.impl.codec.PgCommandCodec.handleReadyForQuery(PgCommandCodec.java:137)
    at io.vertx.pgclient.impl.codec.PgDecoder.decodeReadyForQuery(PgDecoder.java:248)
    at io.vertx.pgclient.impl.codec.PgDecoder.channelRead(PgDecoder.java:107)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:442)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:440)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:842)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect) : [com.example.Services.User.User#2]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:315)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniComposeStage(CompletableFuture.java:1194)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.thenCompose(CompletableFuture.java:2309)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.thenCompose(CompletableFuture.java:144)
    at org.hibernate.reactive.event.impl.DefaultReactiveMergeEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultReactiveMergeEventListener.java:337)
    at org.hibernate.reactive.event.impl.DefaultReactiveMergeEventListener.merge(DefaultReactiveMergeEventListener.java:180)
    at org.hibernate.reactive.event.impl.DefaultReactiveMergeEventListener.doMerge(DefaultReactiveMergeEventListener.java:173)
    at org.hibernate.reactive.event.impl.DefaultReactiveMergeEventListener.reactiveOnMerge(DefaultReactiveMergeEventListener.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.reactive.event.impl.DefaultReactiveMergeEventListener.reactiveOnMerge(DefaultReactiveMergeEventListener.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.lambda$fireEventOnEachListener$0(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:153)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniComposeStage(CompletableFuture.java:1187)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.thenCompose(CompletableFuture.java:2309)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.thenCompose(CompletableFuture.java:144)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:153)
    at org.hibernate.reactive.session.impl.ReactiveSessionImpl.fireMerge(ReactiveSessionImpl.java:888)
    ... 99 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect) : [com.example.Services.User.User#2]
    at org.hibernate.reactive.event.impl.DefaultReactiveMergeEventListener.targetEntity(DefaultReactiveMergeEventListener.java:385)
    at org.hibernate.reactive.event.impl.DefaultReactiveMergeEventListener.lambda$entityIsDetached$13(DefaultReactiveMergeEventListener.java:351)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniComposeStage(CompletableFuture.java:1187)
    ... 112 more

Tried to add to the processing chain: .chain(e -> e.persistAndFlush() but it had no effect.

As it turns out, it is necessary to specify the current version of the record (the version field of the record).

Did you mean that you added a field @Version version to the entity? Also, I think you can rewrite the update method as return SessionOperations.withSession( s -> s.merge( user ) );. You don't need the initial find.

Yes, everything will start working if I add version in
{    "token": "343",     "ext_id": 6379007956,     "iint_id": 2664722,     "valid": false,    "version": 1}.
It's just that the first update (when version=0) works with this form:
{    "token": "343",     "ext_id": 6379007956,     "iint_id": 2664722,     "valid": false}.
And thank you very much for your suggestion to change the approach (use SessionOperations.withSession), it works great.
